# How to pass variadic parameters from one function to another in Go

Tags: go, composition, variadic-functions

I'm trying to pass variadic parameters from one function to another in Go. Basically something like this:

```
func CustomPrint(a ...interface{}) (int, error) {
    // ...
    // Do something else
    // ...

    return fmt.Print(a)
}
```

However when I do this `a` is printed like a slice, not like a list of arguments. i.e.

```
fmt.Print("a", "b", "c") // Prints "a b c"
CustomPrint("a", "b", "c") // Print "[a b c]"
```

Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `...` when calling with a slice:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func CustomPrint(a ...interface{}) (int, error) {
     return fmt.Print(a...)
}
func main() {
     CustomPrint("Hello", 1, 3.14, true)
}
```